# Java process pegging CPU at 100% in a Citrix environment

Tags: java, dll, citrix

We have a java based application that runs as an applet in internet explorer.    One of the things that this applet does is load a dll that is used to launch a third party piece of software.   One of our clients has deployed our application in a Citrix environment.   Only with  this client, (who is also the only one running Citrix) do we see a problem where, intermittently, CPU spikes on the Citrix server to 100%.    When we use process explorer to see what is happening, I see that the culprit is MSVCR71.dll.   How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After almost five weeks of effort, I found the answer to this problem.   It had nothing to do with Citrix, nor did it have to do with loading a third party piece of software.   What happened was that I was disposing a JDialog box twice.    The second time I disposed it, the system seized and spiked the CPU.

Comment: Why was not this behaviour apparent on a non-citrix environment ?

Comment: The fact is that the behavior was apparant in a non-citrix environment.  But, when CPU was high, it wouldn't necessarily affect the performance of a stand-alone computer.   Whereas, in a Citrix production environment, when a user pegs the system, the management system posted an alarm.   This combined with the fact that the error only occurred when the user executed a very specific set of actions made detecting the error difficult.   We needed to trace back to the area of code causing the problem.   Using a profiler is what lead us to the answer.